# how to set text color in array adapter in android

Tags: android, listview, text, colors

in my app i have created a list view and added some text in the list. In my coding part the text are been added as an array adapter to have a check box. In the layout i have given a white color for the list view because of this the text appear to be very dull. How to set the text color to be as black.

i have placed the list view in layout file and placed the values for text view in coding.
the following is the part of my coding

```
names = new String[] { "Sequenced","Random" };
list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cardlist);
list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,names));

                list1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

                list1.setItemChecked(0,true);
```

please help me......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the text color in the simple_list_item_checked layout

Comment: copy it into a new layout...here's it code for it...<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@android:id/text1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark" android:paddingLeft="6dip" android:paddingRight="6dip" /> ...you can find the default layouts in your platform/sdk/data/res/layout folder