# Changing text color of Android Gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

Ive got my mail gallery class:

```
public class sub_gallery extends Gallery {

public sub_gallery(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrSet) {
    super(ctx, attrSet);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private boolean isScrollingLeft(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2){ 
       return e2.getX() > e1.getX(); 
    }

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
  int kEvent;
  if(isScrollingLeft(e1, e2)){ //Check if scrolling left
    kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT;
  }
  else{ //Otherwise scrolling right
    kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT;
  }
  onKeyDown(kEvent, null);
  return true;  
}
}
```

And Im calling it like so:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, new ArrayList<String>());
    adapter.add("text1");
    adapter.add("text2");
    adapter.add("text3");
    adapter.add("text4"); 
sub_gallery g = (sub_gallery) findViewById(R.id.sub_gal);
    g.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And my layout is a follows:

```
<com.interfacetesting.android.email.sub_gallery
         android:id="@+id/sub_gal"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#d0d0d0"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:spacing="100px"
         />
```

Everything is working as needed but I cannot figure out how to change the text color inside the gallery (in the array) for the life of me..

Any help would be appreciated :D

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732695/how-to-set-text-color-in-array-adapter-in-android doesn't help?

Comment: i dont think i can implement what they are saying in that topic the same.. I tried, no luck.

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177056/overriding-android-arrayadapter and/or this: http://www.coderanch.com/t/488673/Android/Mobile/styling-items-ListView

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the android:textColor="#000000" property?

Comment: yep, it doesn't work (i think) due to me calling the gallery as <com.interfacetesting.android.email.sub_gallery> in my layout.xml

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this, and what I found worked was to replace `android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item` with a custom item layout, e.g. `R.layout.gallery_item`, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:maxLines="1" 
    android:textColor="@color/gallery_item_color" 
/>
```

Then create a `res/color/gallery_item_color.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:color="#ffadff2f"/> 
    <item android:state_selected="false" 
          android:color="#ffbebebe"/>
</selector>
```